# Get radio value inside iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I go about doing this with jQuery?

Basically the structure:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <iframe>
    <!-- Normal HTML headers omitted -->
    <input type=radio name="myRadio" value=1>First
    <input type=radio name="myRadio" value=2>Second
    <input type=radio name="myRadio" value=3>Third
  </iframe>
  <input type=button value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I tried various examples from the net such as

```
$("input[@type=radio][@checked]");
```

But failed. Even with jQuery form plugin's [.fieldValue()](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#fields) failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `$('#myForm iframe').contents().find('input[name=myradio]').val()`

I'll assume that the iframe contents have already been loaded and are accessible e.g same domain.

Comment: Actually, this worked. I used <input ... val=1> instead of value=1. My fault, typo.

Answer (score 0):

Unless jQuery does some magic I'm not aware of, accessing another frame's DOM requires a little trickery. This may work:

```
var frameDocument = $('#myForm iframe').contentDocument || $('#myForm iframe').contentWindow.document;
$(frameDocument).find('input[type=radio][checked]');
```

And, note this from the jQuery documentation:

> Note the "@" before the attribute name was deprecated as of version 1.2.