# Retrieve iframe values to client side page

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, client-side

How can I retrieve values from the iframe form id, and call it to my client side html.

(client side html)
sample.html

```
<head>
    <script>
        function alertThis(){
            alert(parent.myframe.formsubmit.a_token.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <iframe name = "myframe" src="http://domain.com/sample/index.php">
    <button onClick = "alertThis();">Click Here</button>

</body>
```

(server side php)
index.php

```
<form name = "formsubmit">
      <input id = "a_token"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>"/>
</form>
```

but it does not return any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var doc = window.frames['myframe'].document.getElementById('a_token').value;
alert(doc);

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codepeace

```
<iframe name="myframe" id="myframe" src="http://domain.com/sample/index.php">

function alertThis(){
   var content = window.frames['myframe'].document.forms['formsubmit'].elements['a_token'].value;
   alert(content);
}
```

**EDIT**

Same issue has sorted using jQuery

[Get radio value inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198024/get-radio-value-inside-iframe)

```
$('#myframe').contents().find('a_token').val()
```

Comment: But still doesn't work, I think I just have to find another way to load my php using javascript to get my values stored in php. If you happen to know some ideas, can you lend some ? XD

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan I just checked first solution work with FF, because I used FF. And now I just added which is using jQuery.